# System doesn't boot up after installing Nvidia drivers on Kubuntu 17.04

Tags: drivers, nvidia, kernel, kubuntu

Currently running **Kubuntu 17.04** with **kernel 4.10.0-33-generic**. Every time I try and install Nvidia drivers (no matter which one) my computer boots up to the glowing Kubuntu logo and then my display keeps refreshing and displaying a single underline cursor (_). I can use a virtual console by <kbd>ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>alt</kbd> + <kbd>F2</kbd> and have been using this way to run `sudo apt-get purge Nvidia*` and remove Nvidia packages. after removing, the login screen comes up and system works normally.

I have tried v.380 all the way through the latest at the moment (v.384).
also tried different approaches like synaptic, adding PPA and using the "driver manager" in system settings.

I assume there is some kind of problem with Nvidia and my kernel, because I was using the v.380 before updating the kernel and it was working just fine. I'm quite new to Linux and do not have professional knowledge so if there is anyways to provide logs please inform me.

Comment: For which card would that be?

Comment: I'm not sure if I understand what you're asking, but I have hybrid graphics, 1st one is intel, and the other one is GeForce. The latter is causing problems.

Comment: See [the answer here](https://askubuntu.com/a/61433/3940), esp. go to the section *COMPUTERS WITH TWO VIDEO CARDS IN HYBRID MODE*